# Refactoring my for comprehension to remove the unsafe get calls on the option values

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie

So my for comprehension technically compiles fine currently, but if you look carefully I have a few unsafe `.get` calls on the options.

```
for {
   maybeProduct: Option[Product] <- EitherT.liftF {
        for {
           a <- ADao.get(123).transact(xa)  // ConnectionIO[Option[A]]
           b <- BDao.get(a.get).transact(xa)      // ConnectionIO[Option[B]]
           product <- CDao.get(b.get.productId.get).transact(xa) // ConnectionIO[Option[Product]]
        } yield product
  }

  transaction <- EitherT(
        TransactionDao.insert(..., maybeProduct.map(_.id),...).transact(xa)                    
   )
}
```

I need help refactoring it to remove the unsafe calls in the following lines in the `for comprehension`

```
           a <- ADao.get(123).transact(xa)  // ConnectionIO[Option[A]]
           b <- BDao.get(a.get).transact(xa)      // ConnectionIO[Option[B]]
           product <- CDao.get(b.get.productId.get).transact(xa) // ConnectionIO[Option[Product]]
```

Specifically the call to `a.get` and `b.get.productId.get`

Comment: And what should be the behaviour if the are `None`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the final return type of the EitherT is an Option[Product] so if any of the .get calls are a None, the entire thing should return None.

Comment: Then all you need to use is used `flatTraverse` and `flatMapN`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Where would I use both? I am not that familiar with those but I will look them up.

Comment: Actually, looking more closely at your code, you want to use `OptionT` so you can just `flatMap` everything in the `for`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if I do that, then I get an error on the `transaction <- EitherT` saying something like it requires `cats.data.EitherT[[A]cats.data.OptionT[cats.effect.IO,A],?,?]` ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252118/discussion-between-blankman-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).